# Powershell - Ingesting API json results into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Looking for some help with ingesting data retrieved from an API endpoint and inserting it into SQL Server. This endpoint returns json.

I'm trimming the script to make this more readable. The script gets the data I'm requesting, the issues is the insert into the SQL table.

```
# Pass the `Authorization` header value with the payload we calculate from the id + secret
$Time = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $TimeCardURL -Method Get -Header @{ Authorization = "Bearer ${AuthorizationValue}" } -Body $Body -Certificate $Cert -ContentType 'application/json'


$Time.teamTimeCards | Select-Object associateOID,timeCards

#SQL authentication and insert $Result data 
$serverName = "sql-server"
$databaseName = "database"
$tableName = "table"
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$serverName';database='$databaseName';trusted_connection=true;"
$Connection.Open()
$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$Command.Connection = $Connection
foreach($ID in $associateOID){
$insertquery="
  INSERT INTO $tableName
      ([associateOID],[timeCards])
    VALUES
      ('$associateOID','$timeCards')"
  $Command.CommandText = $insertquery
  $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
$Connection.Close();
```

It's trying to load the entire object `$associateOID` into the column, which is resulting in a `"String or binary data would be truncated in table 'database.table', column 'associateOID'. Truncated value: '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'. The statement has been terminated."`

I'm guessing there is an issue with this section of the script

```
$Time.teamTimeCards | Select-Object associateOID,timeCards
```

EDIT: The issue was I needed to declare the values *inside* the `foreach` statement

This is what I had

```
foreach($ID in $associateOID){
$insertquery="
  INSERT INTO $tableName
      ([associateOID],[timeCards])
    VALUES
      ('$associateOID','$timeCards')"
  $Command.CommandText = $insertquery
  $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
```

This is what fixed it with a little more massaging. Thanks siggemannen for your help

```
foreach($record in $Time.teamTimeCards){
  $aOID = $record.associateOID
  $timeCards = $record.timeCards | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100
$insertquery="
  INSERT INTO $tableName
      ([associateOID], [timeCards])
    VALUES
      ('$aoid', '$timeCards')"
  $Command.CommandText = $insertquery
  $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
```

Comment: Just type $Time to see if Invoke-RestMethod is returning data. After script completes with errors the variable should still contain data.  You can take code above and paste into powershell and run.  Then after errors just type $Time.

Comment: `$associateOID` is not defined in your snippet, and the output from `$Time.teamTimeCards | Select-Object associateOID,timeCards` isn't captured - did you mean the capture the latter and loop over the results with `foreach`, which would require you to access properties on the loop variable, `$ID` in the body?

Comment: `$Time.teamTimeCards | Select-Object associateOID,timeCards` is just going to output information to the default location, e.g.: the console. It's not going to be passed into your SqlCommand.

Comment: Can you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75487712/edit) your question to produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The important part is getting the JSON data inserted into a SQL table so it should include an example of the JSON you're working with as well. It doesn't need to show how you're retrieving the JSON, you could just specify a string with JSON formatted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your code to use another source of data, but you probably get the idea:

```
$output = Get-Process | Select-Object Handles, Id, ProcessName
echo($output)

foreach($value in $output){
$id = $value.Id
$name = $value.ProcessName
$insertquery="
  INSERT INTO $tableName
      ([ID],[Name])
    VALUES
      ('$id','$name')"
  echo($insertquery)
  
}
```